# NotificationListenerService with RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener crashes on API18 (4.3)

Tags: android, service, android-notifications, android-4.4-kitkat

### The Problem

I want to implement the new [RemoteController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html) API, which has been [introduced with API19 (Kitkat,4.4)](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-4.4.html#Multimedia). The API requires me to implement a class which extends from [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) (introduced with API18) and implements the [RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener.html) interface. (Further information on how to implement all this can be found [here](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?p=52891445) and a very helpful example project can be found [here](https://github.com/DrBreen/RemoteControllerExample))

Everything's working as it should on my API19 (Kitkat,4.4) device and every other API<18 device. However the problem is, that the app crashes right away on API18 (Jelly bean, 4.3), because the "android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" is being sent and starts my RemoteService, which then crashes the app instantly with the following Stacktrace:

```
05-24 09:32:48.945      893-893/com.example E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate service com.example.RemoteService: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.RemoteService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1, /system/lib]]
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2561)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.RemoteService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.example-1, /system/lib]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:53)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleCreateService(ActivityThread.java:2558)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1600(ActivityThread.java:141
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1338)
...
```

This is caused by the simple fact, that [RemoteController](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.html) and therefore the implemented interface [RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener.html) is not available on API18, but [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) is. The intent is not being sent on every device

### What I've tried so far

- Put another layer of abstraction on it and build a simple "if (API>=19)" check.
  I tried to do this by using a second empty [NotificationListenerService](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/service/notification/NotificationListenerService.html) which would just work as a kind of callthrough Service. I would put that second Service in my AndroidManifest, so that it receives the intent instead, and then I'd just put the "if (API>=19)" check in its onCreate and start my actual RemoteService from there. The result is, that my App doesn't crash any more (yay). Unfortunately it also doesn't work in API19 Kitkat any more :(. I think that's because I have to register my RemoteService as a listener in my AndroidManifest directly, or otherwise it won't receive anything.

### Code snippets

RemoteService.java:

```
public class RemoteService extends NotificationListenerService
    implements RemoteController.OnClientUpdateListener {
...
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<manifest ...>
    <application ...>
        <service android:name="com.example.RemoteService"
             android:label="@string/app_name"
             android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### The solution

Put a bool in an xml file in values and values-v19. Set it to false in values and to true in values-v19. Now set the NotificationListenerService's "android:enabled" tag to this bool.

**./values/bool_switches.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="remotecontrollerservice_enabled">false</bool>
</resources>
```

**./values-v19/bool_switches.xml:**

```
<resources>
    <bool name="remotecontrollerservice_enabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

**./AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
...
<service android:name=".services.RemoteControllerService"
         android:label="@string/scrobblingservice_string"
         android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
         android:enabled="@bool/remotecontrollerservice_enabled">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Just disable the service with android:enabled="false", then in Application.onCreate enable it if the device is running KitKat or newer.

Comment: But wouldn't that mean that the system can't instantiate the service on its own? If I restart the device without opening my app again, the system should still be able to start my service and therefore enable me to process the incoming data.

Comment: I've updated the solution which is kind of based on your suggestion.