# Start different services depending on Android Version

Tags: android, service, notifications, version, android-4.4-kitkat

my Android App should control other music players (like Poweramp, Google Music...).
Until now I used the RemoteController class inside a NotificationListenerService.
The service is declared in the Manifest file.

But now in Lollipop, the RemoteController class is deprecated and I want to use the MediaController (which is also in a NotificationListenerService - also declared in the Manifest)

```
<service
        android:name=".......MusicReceiverKitKat"
        android:label="@string/service_KitKat"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">>
        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>


<service
        android:name="......MusicReceiverLollipop"
        android:label="@string/service_Lollipop"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="true" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
</service>
```

But now, both services are started on both - KitKat and Lollipop devices. Also two Apps appear in the Notification Access List.

But I only want to start the Lollipop service in Android 5 and the KitKat service in Android 4.4. And I also want to only show the particular App in the Notification Access List.

My solution was to check in the onCreate() Method of the Services, if it is the right Android version and if not, return. But I think there must be a better way.

It would be kind if somebody could help me out. Thank you!

**UPDATE**

To precicise my question:
The problem is, that If I declare the services in the manifest-file, they are started automatically - independant of the android version. For Lollipop, this works, but for KitKat it crashes, because I used @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) in the Lollipop-Class and therefore it can't find this class. I thought about throwing both classes in one and decide in the onCreate() method, which objects (RemoteController or MediaController) to use, but I think this would be ugly.

Also it would be nice to only have one item in the list of apps, which can have notification access. But I think, they will appear in this list automatically, if I declare the services in the manifest-file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just figured out, how to do this.
The key is the "enabled" flag, you can provide to the service in your manifest-file.

Then you can do it like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/23845884/1894572.

Created a "normal" bool.xml and one bool.xml for v-21 (Lollipop).

This is the normal:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="remoteControllerService_enabled">true</bool>
    <bool name="mediaControllerService_enabled">false</bool>
</resources>
```

and this the one for v-21:

```
<resources>
    <bool name="remoteControllerService_enabled">false</bool>
    <bool name="mediaControllerService_enabled">true</bool>
</resources>
```

Then in the manifest-file:

```
<service
        android:name="....MusicReceiverKitKat"
        android:label="@string/service_KitKat"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="@bool/remoteControllerService_enabled" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action   android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>

<service
        android:name="....MusicReceiverLollipop"
        android:label="@string/service_Lollipop"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_NOTIFICATION_LISTENER_SERVICE"
        android:enabled="@bool/mediaControllerService_enabled" android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.service.notification.NotificationListenerService" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

This works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must read about [Supporting Different Platform Version](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html#version-codes). You can check the Android build version and place it in the `if` statement. For example:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){ // for lollipop
    // your RemoteController class for lollipop is loaded here

} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT == Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT){ // for kitkat
    // your RemoteController class for kitkat is loaded here

} else { // if above statements is not fulfilled
    // you can use your default RemoteController class here
}
```

Place this code in your `NotificationListenerService`. The most important is you must understand about using `else-if` statement.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer and sorry for the late feedback, but this doesn't help very much. If I understood the documentation right, the NotificationService gets started automatically. Also I need both services in the manifest - and therefore both services appear in the list of apps in the Notification Access Settings of Android. I think I need some sort of if-else in the Manifest...